# Expected Value question about married couples

Tags: probability

A group of 36 people, consisting of 18 married couples, are put into random teams of three for a scavenger hunt. In particular, let $a_1,a_2,\ldots,a_{36}$ be the people, and assume that for each $i\in[1..18]$, the pair $(a_{2i-1},a_{2i})$ is a married couple. An event organizer randomly permutes the people, and then for each $k\in[1..12]$ assigns the people in positions $3k-2$, $3k-1$, and $3k$ to Team $k$. How many of the teams should we expect to contain married couples?

Am I in the right track with the following :

Let $A_i$ be the probability that a given team has a married couple. $P(A_i)$ = $(18\times 34)$/${36}\choose{3}$

So we can think of $A_i$ = 1 if team has a married couple and $A_i$ = 0 if the team doesn't have a married couple.

So we can find the expected value of A if we find the expected values of $A_1$ + $A_2$ + ....$A_{18}$.

Since we know the probability that a team has a married couple is $(18\times 34)$/${36}\choose{3}$, would the expected number of teams with married couples be :

E[A] = E[$A_1$ + $A_2$ + ....$A_{18}$] = 18 x $(A_i)$ or (18) x $(18\times 34)$/${36}\choose{3}$

Comment: Well...what's the probability that a randomly selected triple has no couples?

Comment: Suggestion: Try first to study a simpler problem with 6 persons and 2 teams. And then, 12 persons and 4 teams. Is there a pattern?

Comment: @lulu would it be 1 - ($(18\times 34)$/${36}\choose{3}$)?

Comment: Yes, it would!  So then you know the probability that a randomly selected triple does contain a married couple.  And once you know that linearity tells you...

Comment: Note:  Your expression, while correct, is unnecessarily complicated.  Having chosen one person, the next does not make a couple with probability $\frac {34}{35}$.  Then, conditioned on that, the third also fails to make a couple with probability $\frac {32}{34}$.  Hence the answer is the product $\frac {34}{35}\times \frac {32}{34}$.  As I say, that's the same as what you wrote, but maybe it's easier to work with.

Comment: $A=A_1+\ldots+A_{12}$, not $A_{18}$.

Answer (score 1):

I agree with your first step. However, there are 12 teams, not 18 teams because each team has 3 people. Therefore, the answer should be $$\sum_{i=1}^{12} P[A_i] = \frac{12*18*34}{{36 \choose 3}}$$